# How to move Activity to mapActivity in android application

Tags: android, android-maps

I have one application. I need to display a map view when we click on Help button. Actually the Help button is in one class and google map is in another class. Now how can we call one map activity class from another activity class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You launch the activity using an Intent:

- http://getablogger.blogspot.com/2008/01/android-how-to-launch-activity.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html